# Sharepoint Online Modern = Right formula crashes

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

Using Sharepoint Online Modern experience.
I am trying to use the right formula in a column with a calculated value and get an Sharepoint error.
I have a column named LOCATION and has a string value of "ST-BERNARD @ 140".
I create another calculated column with function =right(LOCATION,4) to extract the "140" but get sharepoint error.
But when I enter =right(LOCATION) I get a value of "0".
The column does accept the lenght of the extraction.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer but I don't know why Sharepoint modern only accept ; and not ,
Example intead of using RIGHT(COLUMN,4) I had to use RIGHT(COLUMN;4)
All the documentation was always specifiying a comma not a semi-colunm

Answer (score 0):

The RIGHT function extracts a given number of characters from the right side of a supplied text string. For example, RIGHT("apple",3) returns "ple".

Right(LOCATION,4) should return "@ 140", but an error occurs because it contains the special character @.

Right (LOCATION) will not return any value, so it is displayed as "0".